# How can I put in Textbox of form data which I select from DB?

Tags: python

This is my `.py` code:

```
import web

import MySQLdb

urls = ('/', 'query')

tmpl = web.template.render('templates/')


class query:

    form = web.form.Form(
        web.form.Textbox('title', web.form.notnull, 
            description="I need to:"),

    )

    def GET(self):

        """ Show page """
        res = db.select('student',where="name='Bob'")

        self.form.Textbox=res

        return tmpl.index( self.form)


app = web.application(urls,globals())

db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='std', user='root', pw='123456')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run()
```

and this is `.html` file:

```
$def with ( form)

<form action="" method="post">

$:form.render()

</form>
```

I want to put data which was taken from database in textbox of form. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
self.form.title = res
```

And `res` can be list of results so maybe you will have to do

```
if len(res) > 0:
   self.form.title = res[0]
```